# Java switch within while loop

Tags: java

I have the following JAVA code where a case is within a Runnable on a NIO application.

As part of the app I am trying to decode the contents of myBuffer

```
  while  ((bytesRead = myChannel.read(myBuffer)) > 0) {
      myBuffer.flip();
      myBuffer.mark();

      //... do stuff ...

      switch (myType) {
           case '1':
                 // ... read buffer and do stuff ...
                break;
           case '2':
                // ... read buffer and do stuff ...
                break;
      }
  }
  // I should not be here
```

I've noticed that the breaks instead of breaking the switch statement, are breaking the while loop, sending me to `I should not be here`.

Is there a way of preventing this behaviour and sending the process back into myBuffer.flip() ?

The full code is in here:

https://github.com/trixpan/nifi-lumberjack-bundle

Comment: Have you tried using continue instead of break?

Comment: Are you sure that `myChannel.read` returns > 0   ?

Comment: A break statement with no label attempts to transfer control to the innermost enclosing switch, while, do, or for statement of the immediately enclosing method or initializer; Look at the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15)

Comment: Any chance there's at least one break outside a case/default statement?

Comment: Please provide a code snippet that reproduces the behavior you are describing.

Comment: I'd say you didn't yet post code that breaks out of while loop from switch.

Comment: `break` within `switch` does not end a loop - but a finished data stream will, in your case. Also : you are missing the `default` case and `while([assignment] [comparison])` is (very) bad code, that will not behave as you expect it to in every single case. Always break down algorithms into the smallest possible pieces, no matter what.

Comment: This is not how Java normally works. Breaks in a switch in a while loop do not break out of the while loop. Something else must be happening. Show your complete code, or debug it and see if the condition of the `while` is becoming `false`.

Comment: @Jesper - code reference added

Comment: this is not the switch/break which breaks the while. This is surely while  ((bytesRead = myChannel.read(myBuffer)) > 0)  which stops !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [actual code](https://github.com/trixpan/nifi-lumberjack-bundle/blob/master/nifi-lumberjack-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/lumberjack/ListenLumberjack.java) reads:

```
logger.info("We are outside the loop and position is " + String.valueOf(socketBuffer.position()));
```

The text of this message is incorrect - it is **inside** the loop.

Your main issue could be with your:

```
while  ((bytesRead = myChannel.read(myBuffer)) > 0)
```

As NIO is asynchronous it is quite possible for `read` to return `0`. Thjis does not indicate that the cahnnel is finished - it just means that there is no more data in the channel **at this time**. You should really use:

```
while  ((bytesRead = myChannel.read(myBuffer)) >= 0)
```

And handle the `== 0` case yourself.

Comment: don't pay too much attention to the text of the messages as I have been playing around them. That line was referring to the switch statement but was moved around as I try to understand the behavior

Comment: @AndredeMiranda - Added further details of possible issue.

Comment: There is a problem that NIO can actually read any number of bytes up to myBuffer.length, not only 0,-1 or full.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I think you found it... :-) Thanks!

Comment: @Andre de Miranda be aware, read my comment above, because the number of bytes readed can not only be 0 or full.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki I did read it and will take in consideration. Will have to put some serious thought in this... Life is hard when you try to learn java coding a connector from hell. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I was surprised with the answers posted above, and I thought I have some misconception about how java runs the code and the `break` might break the while loop but misconception was cleared with simple java snippet I tried:

```
Random r = new Random();
    while  (true) 
    {
        System.out.println(" Inside while");
        int myType = r.nextInt();

        switch (myType) {
        case 1:
            // ... read buffer and do stuff ...
            break;
        case 2:
            // ... read buffer and do stuff ...
            break;
        default :
        break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" Outside while");
```

And to my surprise the Java code was giving be exception on line  `System.out.println(" Outside while");` saying **Unreachable code**.

So I am sure that `while` in your question breaks due to condition `while  ((bytesRead = myChannel.read(myBuffer)) > 0)` or you have some misplaced `break` statement outside `switch`

Comment: and the explanation is simple : **`break` does not propagate** in languages like Java. In other languages this is actually possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a label, it will teach you how to mark a loop, but without it in this example it is working same way:

```
        while  ((bytesRead = myChannel.read(myBuffer)) > 0) {
              myBuffer.flip();
              myBuffer.mark();

              //... do stuff ...

              choose: switch (myType) {
                   case '1':
                         // ... read buffer and do stuff ...
                        break choose;
                   case '2':
                        // ... read buffer and do stuff ...
                        break choose;
                   }
              }
              // I should not be here
}
```

But it is working fine, the break inside a case breaks only case, your while is probably ending and you are supprised by that.

Comment: To teach the asking person that it is not breaking a loop because of the break inside a case.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki Good call on teaching but I tried it before. I guess there's something broken in the code but I sincerely cannot see it. :-\

Answer (score 1):

The `myChannel.read(myBuffer)` is not guaranteed to read the whole length of myBuffer, you need to write better reading method, to assure that you readed up to fill entirely myBuffer, it may be the reason.